# What is the standard SQL type for binary data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hsqldb

I have a function which maps java to SQL types.
As I want to store binary data, is there any type defined by the SQL standard which I can use both in PostgreSQL and hsqldb?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [SQL 92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) does not define a binary type.  PostgreSQL has a `bytea` type, hsqldb has a `binary` type.

For a very portable (if not efficient) solution, convert the binary to [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), and store it in a string.

Comment: The poeple who specified SQL don't seem to be very wise...I think I will do the first solution. I need hsqldb for unit testing and postgres for permanent storage, so this should be okay.

Comment: @user3001: I'd recommend to avoid using different database for unit testing than for production. It degrades value of your tests. It is fairy easy to automatically setup temporary Postgres database listening on localhost and some high port (or just a Unix domain socket on Unices) for testing.

Comment: @user3001: You said, "The poeple [sic] who specified SQL don't seem to be very wise". I know one of the guys on the committee. I'll tell him what you think. He probably won't sleep at all.

Comment: I don't think the SQL:1992 standard is appropriate here because it has been long deprecated. I think it still has its uses e.g. it can be asserted that all SQL products should implement entry level SQL:1992 but then the same can said of the core of the current standard. But questions such as, "Does this exist the SQL standard" should reference the current standard, IMO.

Answer (score 8):

BINARY and VARBINARY are defined by the the SQL Standard. The Standard is currently at SQL:2011 (after 92, 1999, 2003 and 2008). HSQLDB supports all the core data types defined by the Standard.

The PostgreSQL BYTEA is similar to VARBINARY. You can define the BYTEA type in HSQLDB as a VARBINARY type with a large maximum size:

```
CREATE TYPE BYTEA AS VARBINARY(1000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL has supported binary types since 1999: [https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-data-types/]. Vendors have had over a decade to add support for binary types, and most SQL databases do.